# Parallel foreach changes data to NA when running dropterm

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, modeling, gam

I have a GAMLSS model I'm trying to fit to multiple subsets of my data. Each month needs to be analyzed separately, so I'm using a foreach loop to iterate through the months. However, when I parallelize my loop, the results of `dropterm` all get NA'd. Here's a similar example using built-in data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gamlss)
library(MASS)
nCores <- detectCores()
gamlssCl <- makeCluster(nCores)
registerDoParallel(gamlssCl)
test.par <- foreach(s = unique(iris$Species), 
                    .packages = c('dplyr', 'gamlss', 'MASS')) %dopar% {
  species.data <- filter(iris, Species == s)
  model <- gamlss(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
                  data = species.data, 
                  family = GA)
  var.rank <- dropterm(model, test = 'Chisq') %>%
    mutate(Variable = row.names(.)) %>% 
    arrange(AIC) %>%
    filter(Variable != '<none>')

  var.rank
}
stopCluster(gamlssCl)
test.par
# [[1]]
# Df AIC LRT Pr(Chi)     Variable
# 1 NA  NA  NA      NA Sepal.Length
# 2 NA  NA  NA      NA  Sepal.Width
# 3 NA  NA  NA      NA Petal.Length
# 
# [[2]]
# Df AIC LRT Pr(Chi)     Variable
# 1 NA  NA  NA      NA Sepal.Length
# 2 NA  NA  NA      NA  Sepal.Width
# 3 NA  NA  NA      NA Petal.Length
# 
# [[3]]
# Df AIC LRT Pr(Chi)     Variable
# 1 NA  NA  NA      NA Sepal.Length
# 2 NA  NA  NA      NA  Sepal.Width
# 3 NA  NA  NA      NA Petal.Length

test.serial <- foreach(s = unique(iris$Species)) %do% {
  species.data <- filter(iris, Species == s)
  model <- gamlss(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
                  data = species.data, 
                  family = GA)
  var.rank <- dropterm(model, test = 'Chisq') %>%
    mutate(Variable = row.names(.)) %>% 
    arrange(AIC) %>%
    filter(Variable != '<none>')

  var.rank
}
test.serial
# [[1]]
# Df       AIC        LRT   Pr(Chi)     Variable
# 1  1 -31.66335 0.06406465 0.8001832  Sepal.Width
# 2  0 -29.72741 0.00000000        NA Petal.Length
# 3  1 -29.43731 2.29010516 0.1302011 Sepal.Length
# 
# [[2]]
# Df      AIC       LRT      Pr(Chi)     Variable
# 1  0 31.03608  0.000000           NA Petal.Length
# 2  1 33.81852  4.782442 2.875132e-02  Sepal.Width
# 3  1 56.00459 26.968510 2.067972e-07 Sepal.Length
# 
# [[3]]
# Df      AIC         LRT      Pr(Chi)     Variable
# 1  1 16.29265  0.08628226 7.689578e-01  Sepal.Width
# 2  0 18.20637  0.00000000           NA Petal.Length
# 3  1 77.14978 60.94341742 5.873901e-15 Sepal.Length
```

Note: The error doesn't manifest when using `glm` instead of `gamlss`

Comment: The example doesn't replicate your problem on my machine. Maybe a redundant question, but do you have the latest version of all packages (and R) and did you already try running the code after rebooting R?

Comment: I also cant replicate . If Vandenman's suggestion doesn't help can you update your question with your `sessionInfo()` please.

Comment: Funny, I can replicate the problem on R 3.2.3...
[sessionInfo() incoming...]
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] splines   parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: other attached packages:
[1] gamlss_4.4-0      nlme_3.1-128      gamlss.dist_4.3-6 MASS_7.3-45       gamlss.data_4.3-4 dplyr_0.5.0       doParallel_1.0.10 iterators_1.0.8  
[9] foreach_1.4.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.6      lattice_0.20-33  codetools_0.2-14 assertthat_0.1   R6_2.1.2         grid_3.2.3       DBI_0.4-1        magrittr_1.5    
 [9] lazyeval_0.2.0   Matrix_1.2-6     tools_3.2.3      compiler_3.2.3   survival_2.39-5  tibble_1.1

Comment: @AlexR; are you able to update your R version, install packages and then try again? I couldnt see anything in the 'Depends' for the loaded packages, but that doesnt mean something hasnt slipped by. [although that said it looks like the op has lost interest;))

Comment: @user20650 I'm not really into updating all my stuff every few months when a new version is out :) But it's nice to know that this is a thing to keep in mind wich might pose me problems in my own tasks. You're on 3.3.1, I assume?

Comment: Yes, on 3.3.1 on ubuntu. Version stuff does can give unexpected results (to the point that they are almost expected)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on R 3.3.3 (Linux) when using snow cluster as in OPs example, e.g. using `cl <- makeCluster(2); registerDoParallel(cl))`.  It does not occur with a forked cluster, which you get if you're on non-Windows and use `registerDoParallel(2)`.  That's an important different when it comes to troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, no solution yet, but here's a minimal example that illustrate the issue and that doesn't depend on foreach.

First, do:

```
library("gamlss")
data <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa")
model <- gamlss(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, 
                data = data, family = GA)
## GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = -37.7274 
## GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = -37.7274

model2 <- dropterm(model, test = "Chisq")
print(model2)
## Single term deletions for
## mu
## 
## Model:
## Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length
##              Df     AIC     LRT Pr(Chi)
## <none>          -29.727                
## Sepal.Length  1 -29.437 2.29011  0.1302
## Sepal.Width   1 -31.663 0.06406  0.8002
## Petal.Length  0 -29.727 0.00000
```

and then save the results to file:

```
saveRDS(list(model = model, model2 = model2), file = "gamlss.rds")
```

Then *in a fresh R session* (`R --vanilla`), do:

```
> library("gamlss")
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: gamlss.data
Loading required package: gamlss.dist
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: nlme
Loading required package: parallel
 **********   GAMLSS Version 5.0-1  ********** 
For more on GAMLSS look at http://www.gamlss.org/
Type gamlssNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.

> gamlss <- readRDS("gamlss.rds")
> model <- gamlss$model
> class(model)
[1] "gamlss" "gam"    "glm"    "lm"   

> model2 <- dropterm(model, test = "Chisq")
Model with term  Sepal.Length has failed 
Model with term  Sepal.Width has failed 
Model with term  Petal.Length has failed 

> print(model2)
Single term deletions for
mu

Model:
Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length
             Df     AIC LRT Pr(Chi)
<none>          -29.727            
Sepal.Length                       
Sepal.Width                        
Petal.Length
```

Compare the output of `model2` in the fresh R session compared to that of the first session above;

```
> all.equal(model2, gamlss$model2)
[1] "Component “Df”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 1 in current 4 in target"     
[2] "Component “AIC”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 0 in current 3 in target"    
[3] "Component “LRT”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 1 in current 4 in target"    
[4] "Component “Pr(Chi)”: 'is.NA' value mismatch: 2 in current 4 in target"
```

Something is clearly not correct here.

I suspect that the `model` object contains one or more so-called *promises* that are not preserved correctly when transferred to another R process (as is the case when you use SNOW clusters).

I would argue this is an issue with the [gamlss](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gamlss) package itself.  The problem appears to be that gamlss object cannot be *serialized*.  I suggest that you report this to the package maintainer.  Feel free to use my minimal example in your report.